# code runs on one OS is not working on different OS

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I written the php code which used stored procedure of mysql database having return output parameter.

I executed that code on my pc having windows 7 os. its get executed and I get proper return value of stored procedure.

but when I run same code on different machine having linux os system. its giving me wrong result. it gives me null value return from stored procedure.

how this is possible ?

Below is my php code

```
\DB::statement('CALL caption_management('.$user_account_id_fk.','.$message_id_fk.','.$message_unique_id_fk.',"'.$message_caption.'",'.$caption_mode.',@solr_flag)');
 $results = \DB::select('select @solr_flag as solr_flag');  
                     var_dump($results);
```

--  var_dump($results)  this returns me result 0 or 1 when I run this on my pc
but returns null when run on other machine having linux system.

Comment: Do both your systems have the same data in the db?

Comment: having different data with same database structure

Comment: So there is your answer.  Run the query with a database tool, if the data does not match, it's a data problem, fix that first.

Comment: its working fine when I run stored procedure with different database